# Loading and/or attaching `package:DBI` and `package:odbc` et al.?

Tags: r, odbc, dbi

I found no explicit guidance in DBI documentation on how to load the front-end (i.e. `package:DBI`) and the back-end (e.g. `package:odbc`).

[Most examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/DBI.html) in the documentation ([but not all](https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/getting-started/connect-to-database/)) attach `package:DBI` to the search path and do not attach the back-end, e.g.:

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...)
```

There was also [a commit](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/192) to favor this.

Why does the documentation use that method rather than e.g.:

```r
# attaching only the back-end
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), ...)

# attaching the back-end before attaching package:DBI
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), ...)

# attaching the back-end after attaching package:DBI
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), ...)
```

?

So far, I only found that the first alternative may cause issues, e.g. for [`package:duckdb`](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/384).

Comment: `odbc` (and other driver-packages) provide the internals required but may not implement every single method that `DBI` provides. I've seen people use `odbc::dbConnect`, and it still seems to work for them. I have not seen anybody complain that using the `odbc::`-variants of `DBI`'s functions has directly caused a problem. I use `DBI`, period.

Comment: **Q1**: I've not seen any issues (yet) with attaching _only_ the driver-backend package. I don't do it. **Q2**: No. There is no masking, just S3 method dispatch, which is different. **Q3**: If you load the backend driver only, then your command will either clearly fail or send possibly-dialectually-inappropriate SQL to the DBMS. **Etc**: I've not seen a bug-report to suggest that loading the driver-only has caused failures, though I do not stalk the repos. Perhaps a rare issue: if you ever change backends, and if you hard-code `odbc::`, then you'll need to rewrite _everything_.

Comment: YES, DBI provides low-level connectivity to the database. Package odbc does not implement all the methods of DBI. Check this gist (https://gist.github.com/arora123/9af5e2d8366ad62017d4a87caeac0f7a) that supports this argument. 
I prefer DBI

Comment: @DrNishaArora Nice example, thanks. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments from @r2evans, `package:odbc` (and other back-end packages) provide the internals required but may not implement every single method that `package:DBI` provides.

Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/arora123/9af5e2d8366ad62017d4a87caeac0f7a) from @DrNishaArora where attaching only the back-end fails:

```r
library(odbc)
conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), "xxx")
dbReadTable(conn, "A_TABLE_IN_THE_DB")
# Error in dbReadTable(conn, "A_TABLE_IN_THE_DB") : 
#   could not find function "dbReadTable"
```

It works as expected when attaching only `package:DBI`:

```r
library(DBI)
conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "xxx")
dbReadTable(conn, "A_TABLE_IN_THE_DB")
```

Comment: I think the spirit of your answer is correct, but you could improve the wording a bit because odbc does provide the needed _methods_, it just doesn't re-export the DBI generics. (Because the expectation is that you will load DBI to get them)